# What are the differences between the two sentences?

Tags: grammar, comparison

Bill makes fewer mistakes than I do.

Bill doesn't make more mistakes than I do.

I guess, 'Bill makes fewer mistakes than I do.' means
I RARELY make mistakes,
but Bill makes much smaller number of mistakes than I do.

whereas, 'Bill doesn't make more mistakes than I do.' means
I OFTEN make mistakes,
but Bill doesn't make as many mistakes as I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one certainly doesn't have that implication.

> Bill makes even fewer mistakes than I do.

would imply that I don't make many, but without the *even*, it doesn't have that implication. If anything, it suggests that I make a lot of mistakes, but if it suggests that it does so weakly.

> Bill doesn't make more mistakes than I do.

is understandable, but not idiomatic. It is only like to be said as a direct denial of "Bill makes more mistakes than you do", and it's hard to think of a case in which that is likely to occur.

On the other hand

> Bill doesn't make as many mistakes as I do.

is idiomatic. That does have at least a suggestion that I make a lot of mistakes, though I wouldn't put it as strongly as an implication.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I want to make line feed but I'm sorry it's yet difficult for me m(_ _)m

Basically these two sentences indicate the difference between two people,
not showing the absolute ability to not make mistakes.

But rather,
'A do as few as B do'
implies B seldom make mistakes,

and 'A do not do as many as B does'
implies B often make some mistakes.

Comment: If you mean you're trying to make a line break in a comment, there's no way to do that. Your first example is right, but your second is not. _Few_ and _many_ are not symmetrical. _Many_ is the default, so in expressions like _how many_ or _as many as_ there is no implication that the number is large - it can be anywhere on the scale. But _few_ is marked: if you choose _how few_ or _as few as_, you are implying that the number is small. It's similar to the way _As short as Jack_ implies that Jack is short, but _as tall as Jack_ does not imply anything about Jack's height.  _Tall_ is the default

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.